Counterexample of Ekeland's variational principle
This is the version of the Ekeland's variational principle that i'm studying:

Let $(X, d)$ be a complete metric space, and let $f: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \cup\{+\infty\}$ be a lower semicontinuous functional on $X$ that is bounded below and not identically equal to $+\infty$. Fix $\varepsilon>0$ and a point $x_0 \in X$ such that
$$
f\left(x_0\right) \leq \varepsilon+\inf _{x \in X} f(x) .
$$
Then, for every $\lambda>0$, there exists a point $v \in X$ such that
$$
\begin{aligned}
& f(v) \leq f\left(x_0\right) \\
& d\left(x_0, v\right) \leq \lambda
\end{aligned}
$$
and
$$
\sup _{x \in X\setminus\{v\}} \frac{f(v)-f(x)}{d(v,x)} \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{\lambda}
$$

Here is the question:
I don't understand why the function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ defined as $f(x)=x$ is not a counterexample: $[0,1]$ is complete, the function is continuous and bounded, but $
\sup _{x \in X\setminus\{v\}} \frac{f(v)-f(x)}{d(v,x)}$ is always 1, hence $\varepsilon \geq \lambda$ and so choosing $\lambda = \varepsilon +1$ gives a contradiction.

If $v = 0$, $(f(v) - f(x))/d(v,x) = -1$, not $1$.

As suggested by a comment, there are two case:
If $\varepsilon \geq \lambda$ then the supremum is equal to 1 for every feasible $v$ and, in fact, it is less or equal than $\frac{\varepsilon}{\lambda}$.
If $\varepsilon \leq \lambda$ then $v=0$ satisfy $d(x_0,v)\leq \lambda$ for all $\lambda$, the supremum is equal to $-1$ and in fact it is less or equal than $\frac{\varepsilon}{\lambda}$.
